# JSONAPi::Resource limiting models that can be requested in include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, jsonapi-resources

I am using the Ruby gem [JSONAPI::Resources](https://jsonapi-resources.com/), the model has quite a few related objects, and I don't want to expose all of them to be queried though the `include` option in URL.

`localhost:3000/api/v1/posts?include=author`
but since there are are comments and ratings associated models. This also works

`localhost:3000/api/v1/posts?include=comments`

`localhost:3000/api/v1/posts?include=ratings`

Which is not a desirable effect.
How can it be limited.

Thank in advance.

Comment: This can be done in many ways, how are you actually doing it now?